# Reading flat file via windows command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I have the below flat file

```
ETL details for the last run:

ETL Process Id : 23396187
ETL Name : MY_WORKFLOW
Run Name : MY_WORKFLOW: ETL Run - 2014-06-26 .....
```

I am using the below code to read it

If i run the below

```
findstr /n . D:\MR\BOK\automation\test2.txt | findstr"4:ETL Name:":
```

The output is `4:ETL Name: MY_WORKFLOW`

But when I set it to a variable and echo, it is not giving me anything

> set eplan=findstr /n . D:\MR\BOK\automation\test2.txt | findstr"4:ETL Name:":
>
> echo %eplan%  just gives
> %eplan%

I am new to windows command line, please correct me if I doing something wrong. My ultimate aim is to store it in a variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (`findstr /n . D:\MR\BOK\automation\test2.txt ^| findstr "4:ETL Name:" `) do set "eplan=%%a"
```

(untested)

should set `eplan` correctly (or at least to the string you specify)

A single-quoted string in a `for /f` loop is executed as a command, and `for` receives the output. The `delims=""` clause turns off the default delimiter set. The line-text is applied to the metavariable `%%a`. The caret (`^`) before the pipe tells batch that the pipe is part of the quoted command to be executed, not part of the `for`.

The `set "var=value"` syntax ensures that any trailing spaces on the line (as may be left by some editors) after `value` are not included in the value assigned.